# Why is the padding of 5px not effecting my th?

Tags: css

Why does the padding: 5px inside .slb-table > .slb-thead > tr > th not work?

```
.slb-table > .slb-thead > tr {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
  }

.slb-table > .slb-thead > tr > th {
     padding: 5px;
  }

.slb-table > .slb-tbody > tr > td {
    color: black;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

This is the top of my table in react:

```
<table class="slb-table">
                <thead class="slb-thead">
                    <tr className="text-white" >
                        {this.tableHeader().map((name, key) => (
                            <th scope="col" className="align-middle" key={name}>{name}</th>
```

Comment: It could be better if you can show the current css of your th tags from Chrome Dev Tools or something. With that other people can have better understand about your problem then can give you the right answer

Comment: Technically this should work. I am sure there is some CSS which are overlapping due to which you couldn't see the changes.
Use chrome dev tools to check and see which CSS is getting overlapped and you can close on to the problem from there and get your desired solution.

Comment: You have used className as an attribute / property, should that be being used as class="" instead? Also your attribute / property key= does that require ""?

Comment: This are my th tags in chrome in order from top to bottom:
th {
    text-align: inherit;
} and 
th {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: -internal-center;
}
The second one says user agent stylesheet

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/15muh8js/1/